# Redirecting to a specific page based on conditions (Ionic + React)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ionic-framework, routes, ionic-react

I have made a questionnaire using ionic slides and I am able to create an array called Answers which stores the selected value from each question.

I wanted to enquire how I can now use an if-statement with this array and then navigate to a specific page when I click "Finish" on the last question?

```
const answers = [selected1, selected2, selected3, selected4, selected5];

const s1 = [1,2,1,1,1];

function suggestion(answers: number[] | undefined): void {
        if (answers == s1) {
            **not sure what to do here to navigate**
        }
    }
```

This is the IonButton code:

```
<IonButton class = "finishbttn" size="small" onClick = {()=> suggestion(answers)}> Finish </IonButton>
```

Comment: Follow the examples here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: @mahen23 This is a question about Ionic React; that documentation is for an old version of Ionic with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a link to a page, you should use `routerLink` instead of `onClick()`.  `onClick()` is for doing processing (submitting a form, toggling a value, etc.), while `routerLink` is to link to another page in the router.

*Although it is possible to do a redirect in onClick(), IonRouter can get confused, so it is better to use routerLink.*

So, first change your `<IonButton>` to use `routerLink`.

```
<IonButton routerLink={doRedirect(answerValue)}>Finish</IonButton>
```

This uses a redirect function, so you redirect based on the answer values:

```
const doRedirect = (answers: number[] | undefined) => {
  if (answers === s1) {
    return 'routeForS1';
  }
}
```

You will of course need to create the routes in your router so that the redirects will work.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion! I've tried it but it's not routing to the route I've set in the return function. (It just doesnt do anything)
I've created the routes and everything so not sure why its not working

Comment: @ahsirk83 You need to debug the function; saying you don't know why it isn't working is not enough information to help you.  Try adding `console.log()` inside the function to check when it is called and what values it is seeing (what is the value it gets for `answers`, etc.)